# Font layout algorithm, Win32

Tags: winapi, layout, fonts, render

I'm trying to come up with a platform independent way to render unicode text to some platform specific surface, but assuming that most platforms support something at least kinda similar, maybe we can talk in terms of the win32 API. I'm most interested in rendering LARGE buffers and supporting rich text, so while I definitely don't want to ever look inside a unicode buffer, I'd like to be told myself what to draw and be hinted where to draw it, so if the buffer is modified, I might properly ask for updates on partial regions of the buffer.

So the actual questions. GetTextExtentExPointW clearly allows me to get the widths of each character, how do I get the width of a nonbreaking extent of text? If I have some long word, he should probably be put on a new line rather than splitting the word. How can I tell where to break the text? Will I need to actually look inside the unicode buffer? This seems very dangerous. Also, how do I figure how far each baseline should be while rendering?

Finally, this is already looking like it's going to be extremely complicated. Are there alternative strategies for doing what I'm trying to do? I really would not at all like to rerender a HUGE buffer each time I change tiny chunks of it. Something between looking at individual glyphs and just giving a box to spat text in.

Finally, I'm not interested in using anything like knuth's word breaking algorithm. No hyphenation. Ideally I'd like to render justified text, but that's on me if the word positioning is given. Ragged right hand margin is fine by me.

Comment: You definitely don't want to be using any functions ending in A with Unicode.

Comment: Whoops! Meant W. Sorry

Comment: Your question is a quagmire of possibilities.  "How can I tell where to break text" is a question text rendering engines have been trying to answer satisfactorily for deacades.  As an example, one of the main reasons TeX is still used in academia is because it does a good job of layout out math text.  So good that no one has gotten close in the last 30 years.

Comment: Edited answer. Not interested in anything fancy. I have discovered UAX #14 which might do what I want. Still interested in "lazy" rendering mechanisms supported by the operating system.

Comment: DrawTextEx is about as good as the OS gets.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - DrawTextEx is *really* basic.  GDI+ has better text rendering, and DirectWrite better still.

Comment: @EricBrown: I don't think any of them have much more capability in terms of layout control than DrawText does though.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - DirectWrite has *tons* of layout control.  (More than many people want to know about.)  See [IDWriteTextLayout::SetTypography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371517(v=vs.85).aspx) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called shaping in unicode jargon. Don't bother writing your own shaping engine, it's a full-time job that requires continuous updates to take into account changes in unicode and opentype standards. If you want to spend any time on the rest of your app you'll need to delegate shaping to a third-party engine (harbuzz-ng, uniscribe, icu, etc)

As others wrote:
– unicode font rendering is hellishly complex, much more than you expect
– winapi is not cross platform at all

The three common strategies for rendering unicode text are:
1. write one backend per system (plugging on the system native text stack) or
2. select one set of cross-platform libs (for example freebidi + harfbuzz-ng + freetype + fontconfig, or a framework like QT) and recompile them for each target system or
3. take compliance shortcuts

The only strategy I strongly advise against is the last one. You can *not* control unicode.org normalization (adding upper ss to German), you do *not* understand worldwide script uses (both African languages and Vietnamese are Latin variants but they exercise unexpected unicode properties), you *will* underestimate font creators ingenuity (oh, indic users requested  this opentype property, but it will be really handy for this English use-case…).

The two first strategies have their own drawbacks. It's simpler to maintain a single text backend but deploying a complete text stack on a foreign system is far from hassle-free. Almost every project that tries cross-plarform has to get rid of msvc first since it targets windows and its language dialect won't work on other platforms and cross-platform libs will typically only compile easily in gcc or llvm.

I think harfbuzz-ng has reached parity with uniscribe even on windows so that's the lib I'd target if I wanted cross-platform today (chrome, firefox and libreoffice use it at least on some platforms). However Libreoffice at least uses the multi-backend strategy. No idea if it reflects current library state more than some past historic assessment. There are not so many cross-platform apps with heavy text usage to look at, and most of them carry the burden of legacy choices.

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi: Nice to hear, but the native ui should still use Uniscribe to render text even the blink engine removed the uniscribe dependency https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ui/gfx/render_text_win.cc&q=ScriptLayout&sq=package:chromium&l=1034

Comment: @Jichao: That is also going to be fixed http://crbug.com/321868 and currently is under a flag :)

Answer (score 0):

Unicode rendering is surprisingly complicated.   Line breaking is just the beginning; there are many other subtleties that I don't think you've appreciated (vertical text, right-to=left text, glyph combining, and *many* more).  Microsoft has several teams dedicated to doing nothing but implementing text rendering, for example.

Sounds like you're interested in [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).   Note that this is NOT platform independent, obviously.  It's also possible to do a less accurate job if you don't care about being language independent; many of the more unusual features only occur in rarer languages.  (Chinese being a notable exception.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want some perfect multi platform there will be problems. If you draw one sentence with GDI, one GDI+, one with Direct2D, one on Linux, one on Mac all with the same font size on the same buffer, you'll have differences some round some position to int some other use float for examples.
There is not one, but a least two problems.
 Drawing text and computing text position, line break etc are very different. Some library do both some do only computing or rendering part. A very simplified explanation is drawing do only render one single char at the position you ask, with transformations zoom, rotation and anti aliasing. Computing do everything else chose each char position in word, sentences line break, paragraphs etc
If you want to be platform independent you could use FreeType to read font files and get every information on each characters. That library get exact same result on each platform and predictability in font is good. The main problem with font is lot of bad, missed, or even wrong information in characters descriptions.Nobody do text perfectly because it's very hard (tipping hat to word, acrobat and every team who deal directly with fonts)
If your computing of font is good. There is lot of work to do everything you could see in a good word processor software (space between characters, spaces between word, line break, alignment, rotation, grease, aliasing...) then you could do the rendering. It should be the easier. You can with same computation do GDI, Direct2D, PDF or printing rendering path.